# How to only get update info when you run chef-solo

Tags: chef-infra

I'm a total chef noob, and am right now just trying to update some config files by a bit of trial and error. Its a big pain when you run the chef-solo command to update the server that it spits out a lot of information that I don't care about.

Is there a way to just get output when something actually changes or is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way that you can make Chef print only information on those resources that it changes, because they are on the same log level.

But you can run only the recipe/group of recipes at a time (those that you have changed, for example) by providing `-o` to chef-solo. This way you don't have to wait for the recipes that have already run successfully and you get smaller log too.

```
chef-solo -o mycookbook,role[role-name],mycookbook::recipe1
```